# Load a jQuery plug-in from String

Tags: jquery

I want to do something a little hackish.

Say I have jQuery plug-in code in this variable:

```
var script = '!function( some jQuery plugin )(window.jQuery)';
```

I want to load it. I tried eval(script) and jQuery.globalEval(script). It does not work. If I had this plug-in code in a file, I could do jQuery.getScript(url, callback). But I only have the code in a string. I thought about loading this string in cache associated to a mock URL key, but I do not know if it is possible.

Any suggestions? ...other than, "do not do it". I know the "eval is evil" mantra, but think about this as an academic question.

Key characteristics of the the code in the script variable:

Prologue:

```
!function(a){"use strict";
```

Epilogue:

```
gister(b)})}}(window.jQuery||window.Zepto);
```

Comment: Why do you have a plugin like this?  Just curious.

Comment: Also, what happens when you use `eval()`/`globalEval()`?  How doesn't it work?  Do you see any errors?  What does your plugin look like?

Comment: Does eval says anything in console, or just nothing happens?

Comment: `eval('('+script+')');`

Comment: Can you post the exact prologue and epilogue of the code in your string? As it is, it lacks an opening parenthesis or a unary operator to make the anonymous function self-invocable.

Comment: Correct, I do not have a file to load. Otherwise, jQuery.loadScript() would work. I need to evaluate it and it is a jQuery plug-in (i.e. "load" the plug-in).

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is hackish at all. This happens all the time really. Partial views are returned from ajax calls which contain script that gets executed. It is rather similar to what you are doing. The only downside is that you are going to miss out on having this script be cached.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at it again. eval() does work but I was doing something else wrong (unrelated to this problem).

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do this. `eval` can be used, but it isn't really desirable. Same can be said of constructing a `Function()` with the string. Here are two approaches that can be useful.

---

*A counter-intuitive approach*

This one is pretty neat. It plays on the idea that you can execute code from the url (basically the same way that bookmarklets work). Say you have this variable with your extension in it:

```
var scriptData = "$.fn.jQueryExtension = function(){ this.each(function(){/*code*/}); };";
```

And you want to run that string as code. One liner:

```
window.location = "javascript:"+scriptData;
```

---

*Place it in the page using `.html()`*

You can use jQuery's `.html()` to place it into the page. It will execute script code. This is a very common way to place a partial html page with script that was returned from an ajax call (it can also be useful if there does happen to be some html alongside the code). Say this is in your scriptData variable.

```
var scriptData = "$.fn.jQueryExtension = function(){ this.each(function(){/*code*/}); };";
```

Wrap it in a script element.

```
var scriptHtml = "<script>"+scriptData+"</script>";
```

And the place it as html in the dom.

```
var scriptDiv = $("<div>").html(scriptHtml);
$("body").append(scriptDiv);
```

A very easy way to test that this works is to execute this code from the browser console in this page

```
var scriptData = "alert('test');";
var scriptHtml = "<script>"+scriptData+"</script>";
var scriptDiv = $("<div>").html(scriptHtml);
$("body").append(scriptDiv);
```

Comment: Thanks. It does work. But what's the reason why it would be more desirable than eval() in this particular scenario?

Comment: @FredericFortier - It is definitely a source of contention for using eval or not. I consider it best practice to avoid its use, and so do others such as Douglas Crockford. One thing to consider, what if `eval` was overridden in another library you loaded? "eval has aliases. Do not use the Function constructor. Do not pass strings to setTimeout or setInterval." -D. Crockford.